# Qualtrics: total duration and branching?

Tags: qualtrics

On Qualtrics surveys, is it possible to combine the embedded total-duration variable

```
sb1 = ${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}
```

with a branching condition to move straight to the end of survey?

For example, suppose I want respondents to spend no more than 60 seconds on the survey. Suppose also that I want them moved to the end of the survey when time is up. If I use a branching condition on the sb1 variable after each block to do it, it will allow the last response to be recorded even after time is up.

I tried to get around this by pasting the following javascript on each question, but it's not working:

```
var that = this;  
var elapsed = parseInt("${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}") - parseInt("${e://Field/sb1}"); 
if(elapsed >= 60) { that.clickNextButton() }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The only way to avoid the problem you are seeing is to use javacript to track the tiem passed on page, and bring in the time spend in survey to track if and when to automatically click the next button

Comment: JavaScript would interact with the next button, and then you could use survey flow to control ending the survey after each block.

Comment: If you want to add code, edit your original post, it is much easier to read than a comment!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.